# populate a UITableViewCell containing multiple UILabels from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, uilabel

How can I populate a UITableViewCell containing multiple UILabels from firebase?  I am new to firebase and clueless about this. My app ivloves users posting a couple text elements and others seeing a UITableView populated with that data, and multiple datasets.
btw im not asking you to write an app for me, thx

Comment: My question is: do you understand how to read data from Firebase? If so, show us the code you tried to use to read in your labels from Firebase. You may also want to include your Firebase structure (as text please, no images) so we understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you want this to happen in real time.

**Step 1: Listening**

You will need to use `observe` on a child in your clients for real time updates listening.

**Step 2: Writing**

When a user inputs a text you need to use `setValue` or `updateChildValues` with that data on a child.

**Step 3: Updating**

All your listeners on that child will be notified about the new data. Then you update their `UITableView` dataSource and `reloadData()` to present it.

**Notes:**

If you want multiple "datasets" you should use diferent childs to acchieve that.

If you don't want real time updates you can use `observeSingleEvent` on a child and make a request every time you want the most updated data.

Comment: pfffft. Nothing wrong with this answer. It is kinda 'high level' so I would like to see come code though to help the OP wrap their brain around the concept. Of course, the OP should have included code as well. :-)